# NSFetchedResultsController always including temporary objects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` that I set up as following:

```
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Order")
        fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "status", ascending: false),
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]

        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: DataStoreManager.sharedInstance.mainContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "section",
            cacheName: nil)

        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

The problem is even with the `includesPendingChanges` set to false, it stills calls `controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)` every time I create a new object in the context (without saving).

Is there something else I should look for to avoid this situation?

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you execute the fetch request directly instead of passing it to the FRC? Do you still fetch the unsaved objects? A workaround would be to create new objects in a separate child context, and not save to mainContext until you're ready.

Comment: Tracking changes – that's exactly the point of FRC. I suppose that it simply ignoring `includesPendingChanges`. If you don't need that changes – just execute a fetch, and you'll get a nice immutable `NSArray`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way is to use a child context. The parent should be the main thread managed object context used in the fetched results controller.

If you save, the changes are immediately "pushed" to the main context, i.e. the fetched results controller. (Save the main context to persist to the persistent store.)

If you don't want to save, just discard the child context without saving. The fetched results controller will never know about it.

Comment: Yes. But OP is using `includesPendingChanges` correctly, AFAICT. I couldn't find documentation that NSFRC ignores that setting on its Fetch Request.

Comment: Docs say `includesPendingChanges` works for `NSFetchRequest`. OP is referring to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` callbacks.

Comment: You said to do that when I'm creating a new object, right? I actually've been trying to do something like that (using a child context) to every object that I create, but then I always hit the issue when I have a mandatory relationship but can't create the relationship before saving because the objects are in different contexts.

Comment: You need to fetch the other object (to which there is a relationship you want to set) from the **same** context in which you have created the new object. That's the *only* way, otherwise it should not work anyway.

Comment: @Mundi: great, will try to do that.